# Capturar evento al cerrar modal

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap, modal

Estoy teniendo un problema. Tengo el siguiente codigo en HTML:

```
<a id="accessGeneral" class="simple-modal-atajos botonmas" style="cursor:pointer;"><div class="divbotonmas"><i class="fa fa-plus font18"></i></div></a>

<div class="simple-modal-atajos-content modal-content rounded-modal" style="padding:10px">

</div>
```

Para mostrar el modal utilizo:

```
$(document).on("click", ".simple-modal-atajos", function(evt) {
    $('.simple-modal-atajos-content').modal();
});
```

Y ahora quiero capturar el evento al hacer al cerrar el modal haciendo click fuera de el, pero no estoy pudiendo. He probado con estas variantes:

```
$(document).on("hidden", ".simple-modal-atajos-content", function () {
    alert('se cerro');
});

$(document).on("hide", ".simple-modal-atajos-content", function () {
    alert('se cerro');
});

$(document).on("hidden.bs.modal", ".simple-modal-atajos-content", function () {
    alert('se cerro');
});
```

Pero ninguna parece funcionar.

Comment: Ya probaste con `$('#accessGeneral').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
 
})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En la [documentación sobre eventos](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/modal/#events), puedes capturarlo de la siguiente forma

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (event) {
  // do something...
})
```

Existiendo dos variantes al momento de cerrar:

- hide.bs.modal
- hidden.bs.modal

Veo que implementas llamadas manuales al modal, pero puedes usar los atributos `data-*` de Bootstrap.

```js
$('#accessGeneral').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
 alert("Se abre");
})


$('#accessGeneral').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
  alert("Se cierra");
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#accessGeneral" class="simple-modal-atajos botonmas">ABRIR</a>

<div id="accessGeneral"  class="modal" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">     
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>CONTENIDO</p>
      </div>     
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

El ejemplo utiliza la versión 4.6 de Bootstrap, para la versión 5, que no requiere de jQuery, podrías hacerlo con Vanilla JS:

```
var myModalEl = document.getElementById('myModal')
myModalEl.addEventListener('hidden.bs.modal', function (event) {
  // do something...
})
```